# How to Escape '\'

Tags: c#, string, backslash

While executing my C# Code to Read a .CSV with ADO I have the next issue:
while reading my rows, I get a value contained in a string and split with "\". Something like "hi\goodMorning\ByeBye".

Here is my code:

```
// Crear el objeto de conexión utilizando la cadena de conexión anterior. 
using (OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString))
{
    // Abrir la conexión con la base de datos. 
    objConn.Open();
    // El código utiliza un comando SQL SELECT para mostrar los datos de la hoja de cálculo.
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + fileName;
    // Crear un nuevo OleDbCommand para devolver los datos de la hoja de cálculo. 
    using (OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(sql, objConn))
    {
        // Crear un nuevo OleDbDataAdapter que se usa para generar un DataSet // basado en la instrucción SQL SELECT anterior. 
        // Pasar el comando Select al adaptador. 
        //OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(objCmdSelect);
        OleDbDataReader reader = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string value= @reader[0].ToString();
```

I have been trying so far to do:

```
A -->  string value = reader[0].ToString();

B -->  value .Split(Convert.ToChar(92)); //Using ASCII

C --> System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape("\\")

D --> value.Contains((char)92); //---> returns false

E -->  value.Contains("\\\"); //---> returns false

F --> .Replace doesn't work either
```

I'm out of ideas! Happy to hear any advices. I think the issue will be resolved if I can get to escape the character. So far I couldn't do it. If I get my answer I will post it.

This --> `@"your\string\here".Contains("\\");` --> returns TRUE -- it doesnt

[image]

The right answer in my case was:

```
string []  temp = @"aaa\taaa\taaa".Split('\t');
```

Thank you all! :)

Comment: value.Contains("\") should be true as long as its (@"\")

Comment: if "value.Contains("\\"); ---> returns false" then something is wrong with you string that you check. Because: `@"your\string\here".Contains("\\"); --> returns TRUE`. Please post a screenshot from your debugger showing the value at runtime

Comment: ok what is the first letter behing the \ in your string ?? is it always the same? can it be the case that the string is actually **\t** tab or even **\n** newline separated ?=!

Comment: They are tabs, not slashes. What you are seeing **is** already escaped.

Comment: Check the  image in the initial post for :


 @"your\string\here".Contains("\\"); --> returns FALSE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to escape the escape sequence use it twice:

```
"\\"
```

or use the `@` **verbatim-string-literal** in front of the string. It will force the compiler to interpret the string literally without any escape sequences. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
@"\"
```

That means that is you want to use split you can use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string []  temp = @"your\string\here".Split(new string [] {@"\"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

or the [overload that accepts a char as parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string []  temp = @"your\string\here".Split('\\');
```

`Contains` and `Replace` work similar:

```
bool cont = @"your\string\here".Contains(@"\");

string repl = @"your\string\here".Replace(@"\", " ");
```

EDIT:

After your update it becomes obvious that you string is tab separated:

[image]

you need to split it by `\t` a tab!

```
string []  temp = @"aaa\taaa\taaa".Split('\t');
```

Please read the first link that I posted. The documentation says:

> A character that follows a backslash character () in a regular-string-literal-character must be one of the following characters: ', ", \, 0, a, b, f, n, r, t, u, U, x, v. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: valorCol.Split(@"\");

Error : Cannot convert 'string' into 'char'

While doing .Split("\\"), It never splits... If we do .Contains("\\") It returns false too
But thank you for your quick answer

Comment: @CarmenGonzález-CondeMáiz no. There is an overload that excepts a `string [] ` as parameter. You need to take that one. Also specify the `StringSplitOptions`

Comment: string[] splitValorCol = value.Split(@"\");
  string[] splitValorCol = valorCol.Split("\\");

This doesnt split

Comment: @CarmenGonzález-CondeMáiz there is no overload of the `Split` method that takes only a string. You also need to specify the `StringSplitOptions`. Have a look at my edit

Comment: string []  temp = @"your\string\here".Split(new string [] {@"\"}); doesnt work, there is a problem converting string to char again, but thank.s. Im going to check the StringSplitOptions

Comment: @CarmenGonzález-CondeMáiz still not working? then can you please post a screen shot from the debugger showing the string value that you have ?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález-CondeMáiz have a look at the documentation links that I posted. they are really helpful

Comment: @CarmenGonzález-CondeMáiz your string is tab separated!, you need to split it by `\t`

Comment: I'm very happy to say this is the righ answer:


Split('\t');

Thank you very much  Mong Zhu, you saved the day!!! :D

Comment: @CarmenGonzález-CondeMáiz you are very welcome. The debugger is our best friend ;) have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

To use a backslash character in C#, you need to escape it with another backslash (`'\\'`). Also, the `String.Split` method expects an array of chars (not a single string or char).

So your code should look like this:

```
value.Split(new char[] { '\\' })
```

See this [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gLSEXc) for an online demo.

Comment: Hello, this doenst work either, it doesnt split :(

string[] splitValorCol = @valorCol.Split(new char[] { '\\' });

Comment: It works for me. See this online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gLSEXc . Are you sure that your string actually contains backslash characters?

Comment: there is something fishy with the string that OP is testing. otherwise "value.Contains("\\"); ---> returns false" would return TRUE